# How to apply Principal Components from ZCA Whitening on Deep Learning inference

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm implementing ZCA Whitening as a preprocessing step for a CNN. Following [This blog post](https://hadrienj.github.io/posts/Preprocessing-for-deep-learning/) and several other sources I've been able to obtain the ZCA matrix and apply it to the training dataset (comprised of 5000 images of dimensions 64x200):

```
# Covariance matrix
cov = np.cov(X, rowvar=True)
# Single Value Decomposition
U,S,V = np.linalg.svd(cov)
# Epsilon value
epsilon = 0.1
# ZCA Matrix principal_components. 
tmp = np.dot(U, np.diag(1/np.sqrt(S+epsilon)))
principal_components = np.dot(tmp, U.T)
principal_components.shape
> (5000,5000)
```

Applying this matrix to the training set is trivial, given the matching number of examples. My question is, how do I apply it to test examples during inference time after training?

Given that I have a (64x200) shaped image, how should I go about multiplying the (5000,5000) matrix in order to obtain the whitened version of an input image? I feel like I'm misunderstanding some crucial step in this process.

Thank you!